# Studies of Twin Speak

Tags: language-acquisition

I'm curious about language acquisition among twins. I've heard it said that they often develop their own language (of sorts) and I was wondering if anyone has done any studies of this phenomenon.

- Is it more common in certain languages/ language families?
- Are there societal or gender-based factors to this development?
- How complete is this "language" likely to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The invented languages of twins, sometimes called 'twinspeak' are also known as cryptophasia or idioglossia. Peter Bakker of Aarhus University (Denmark) has published on this topic (abstract available [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3434134)). According to Bakker twin languages are very common, occurring in about 40% of all twins, but soon disappear.

Regarding the structure of these languages, Bakker writes:

> In all cases known, the language consists of onomatopoeic expressions,
>   some invented words, but for the greatest part of words from the adult
>   language adopted to the constrained phonological possibilities of
>   young children. These words being hardly recognizable, the language
>   may turn out to be completely unintelligible to speakers of the model
>   languages, but they resemble each other in that they lack morphology
>   and that word order is based on pragmatic principles such as saliency
>   and the semantic scope of words. Neither the structure of the
>   languages nor its emergence can be explained by other than situational
>   factors.

The Bakker article seems to be hard to obtain. Further reading may be found in the bibliography of the subject Bernard Comrie posted to [LinguistList](http://linguistlist.org/issues/9/9-469.html) in 1998.